# Make [iics] a synonym of [informatica-cloud]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

I just stumbled upon the [iics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iics) which doesn't have any wiki or usage guidelines and is tagged in a whopping 19 questions. IICS is the abbreviation of Informatica Intelligent Cloud Services.

The top two related tags are;

- [informatica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/informatica) x 13 uses

and

- [informatica-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/informatica-cloud) x 8 uses (which is for Informatica Intelligent Cloud Services anyway, as evidenced by its tag wiki)

> Informatica Intelligent Cloud Services is a cloud Integration Platform as a Service (IPaaS) covering ETL, Application Integration, file ingestion, messaging and more via a number of modules like DI, AI, MI, CIH and some additional features on top. It enables customers to design integration interfaces of various nature between cloud and on-premise applications.

which encompass all but [one of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72913070/adls-connectivity-from-linux-server-using-azure-cli) the 19 questions which does mention IICS secure agent which is from [the documentation](https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/cloud-data-integration/current-version/glossary/glossary/glossary-of-terms/informatica-cloud-secure-agent.html)

> A lightweight program that runs tasks and collects metadata for. Informatica Intelligent Cloud Services

so this single question *should* probably be tagged with [informatica-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/informatica-cloud) (I didn't think this was appropriate for myself to do while making this request).

So, in my opinion [iics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iics) does nothing as a standalone tag and should be synonymed to [informatica-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/informatica-cloud) - this also cannot be done manually via the [voting system](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/informatica-cloud/synonyms) as currently only one user meets the criteria for suggesting and one other user for voting.